# Xcode: Expected expression after operator

Tags: swift, xcode

```
    {
        self.myCBControler = CoreBluetoothController()
        self.sozNum = globSozNumber
        self.insert = false
        self.stateStopBLE = true

        print("Initialized Blood Pressure View!!")
        super.init(coder: aDecoder ?? default value)
    }
```

I got the Mistake at the last line with "default value" and "super.init" (I think so)
The ERRORs are: "Expected expression after operator" and "Must call a designated initializer of the superclass 'UIViewController'"
Would be really nice to help us, thanksss

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply pass the parameter that you get in your constructor to your super constructor:

```
override required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder)
{
    self.myCBControler = CoreBluetoothController()
    self.sozNum = globSozNumber
    self.insert = false
    self.stateStopBLE = true

    print("Initialized Blood Pressure View!!")
    super.init(coder: aDecoder)
}
```

You might have to adjust the order of your custom initialization and the super initializer (this depends on the type of your properties):

```
override required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder)
{
    super.init(coder: aDecoder)

    self.myCBControler = CoreBluetoothController()
    self.sozNum = globSozNumber
    self.insert = false
    self.stateStopBLE = true

    print("Initialized Blood Pressure View!!")
}
```